# Mp3 download from URL using RestKit

Tags: ios, ios5, nsurlconnection, restkit

I already googled this and decided to ask here coz results are not that relative.

I am designing an app that downloads mp3 music from a url.
For example i have a music from a web directory, like 
http://www.example.com/music_folder/song.mp3, how can I download it and store it to documents folder in the iPhone using RestKit?

Furthermore, I want to add a slider to show the value changed while downloading the file.

Any references would help.

Thanks much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why would you use RestKit to download it? RestKit is for interacting with REST web services, not for downloading arbitrary files.

I'd suggest you just use NSURLConnection: tutorial [here](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html).

For displaying the progress, look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2267950/how-to-make-an-progress-bar-for-an-nsurlconnection-when-downloading-a-file).

Comment: Thanks for the link. I assumed RestKit to process all kinds of request. My bad. Your second link got me! Thank you so much!

Comment: I don't see why it is not okay to use RestKit to download files, especially when it comes with queue handling already etc ... RestKit implements NSURLConnection itself with lots of stuff around it to make it work properly. Using NSURLConnection is somewhat strange. I have been using it quite often and would prefer RestKit for loading files as well.