# Progress bar while downloading files iOS

Tags: ios, nsdata, uiprogressview

I am using the following to download the files from the internet:

`NSData *myXMLData1 = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"Link]];`

Now, I would like to put a progress bar while the download is going on. I checked various posts but i am not able to find out how to do it exactly.

Please help me!!

Comment: Go through  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2267950/how-to-make-an-progress-bar-for-an-nsurlconnection-when-downloading-a-file

Comment: @Azik
But, I am also having some problem in How to use NSURLConnection. The link you gave is after I use NSURLConnection to download my files?

Answer (score 8):

I would recommend looking into the ASIHTTP library, which contains a lot of usefull classes on mobile handling and download handling.

Here is a link where they describe what ASIHTTP can offer in terms of download progress tracking : http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use#progress

Answer (score 8):

add

```
expectedBytes = [response expectedContentLength];
```

to

```
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection*)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse*)response
```

and add

```
float progress = ((_bytesReceived/(float)_expectedBytes)*100)/100;
```

to

```
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection*)connection didReceiveData:(NSData*)data
```

then setProgress: on your UIProgressView

From:
http://www.developers-life.com/progress-bar-download-file-on-iphone.html