# I want to show activity indicator before image loading in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I get the `image url` from webservice,i has loaded that image in `imageview`.Like as follows..

```
[ImageName setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"image url"]stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding ]]].
```

It has taking time to load image in `imageview`. I want to display activity indicator before loading image in `imageview`.

Comment: check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19831885/set-progress-bar-for-downloading-nsdata) you need to modify the logic in setImageWithURL.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could do it this way :

Add an indicator to your view, place it at the center of your imageview

```
    UIActivityIndicatorView *indicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
    [indicator startAnimating];
    [indicator setCenter:self.imageView.center];
    [self.contentView addSubview:indicator];
```

Remove the indicator from the superview in the block's succes method.

```
     NSUrl *anURL=[NSURL URLWithString:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"image url"]stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding ]];

    [_imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:anURL]
                       success:^(UIImage *image) {
                           [indicator removeFromSuperview];
                       }
                       failure:^(NSError *error) {

                       }];
}
```

Of course you could make a nice subclass for this