# How to get Upload time remaining from Asynchronous Request?

Tags: iphone, ios, progress-bar, image-uploading

I m trying to upload an Image from iPhone to Server. I m Able to Do so But i need to show an Indicator.My code  is

```
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(newImage, 90);

// setting up the URL to post to
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"URL",[[formater stringFromDate:now] stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
// setting up the request object now
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] ;
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
  NSString *boundary = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449"];
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];
 NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"image\"; filename=\"ipodfile.jpg\"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
// setting the body of the post to the reqeust
[request setHTTPBody:body];
```

Here is the code to fire request.

```
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                           completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
                               NSLog(@"Finished with status code: %i", [(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response statusCode]);
 }];
```

So How can i Calculate the Remaining time so that i can Show an indicator ?
Thanks for your time.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make an progress bar for an NSURLConnection when downloading a file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2267950/how-to-make-an-progress-bar-for-an-nsurlconnection-when-downloading-a-file)

Comment: @lxt thanks for your time But i m not looking for that. I know NSURLconnection Delegate methods But i m doing the Upload inside a Block in separate thread.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this method of connection delegate:

```
- (void)       connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection
          didSendBodyData:(NSInteger)bytesWritten
        totalBytesWritten:(NSInteger)totalBytesWritten
totalBytesExpectedToWrite:(NSInteger)totalBytesExpectedToWrite;
```

*(How should I wrap such long argument names?)*
It's not in documentation of `NSURLConnectionDataDelegate`, but if you check the public header `NSURLConnection.h`, it's there. So don't worry about using it.

From documentation *URL Loading System Programming Guide* > *Using NSURLConnection*:

> **Estimating Upload Progress**
>
> You can estimate the progress of an HTTP POST upload with the `connection:didSendBodyData:totalBytesWritten:totalBytesExpectedToWrite:` delegate method. Note that this is not an exact measurement of upload progress, because the connection may fail or the connection may encounter an authentication challenge.

Comment: Hi @iMartin Thanks for the Answer. I already Added this to My code But this method  Not getting called. I added  




`NSURLConnectionDelegate` in .h file also.  is it due to The Following code ?













`[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                           completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
                               NSLog(@"Finished with status code: %i", [(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response statusCode]);
 }];`

Comment: Yes, you will have to use other methods, because you need to set the delegate. For example use `–initWithRequest:delegate:` and then `-start`. Then implement few other delegate methods to check for completion or error.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want to show something like a progress bar. I recomend using the MKNetworkKit that provides you many tools for network management, such as progress of an asynchronous connection. Check this [link](https://github.com/MugunthKumar/MKNetworkKit).

Comment: Hi @CainaSouza Thanks for your response. I don't want to use any third Party Library for this small task. That kit will be usefull for the complex tasks.