# Calculate amount of image data uploaded to Facebook or Twitter

Tags: ios, facebook, ios5, twitter, ios6

I have to post image to facebook and twitter.The requirement is to provide a progressive HUD which says how much data has been uploaded.Is there any delegate method in facebook sdk or twrequest to know the amount of data uploaded to respective server

Comment: It depends what API you are using; care to tell us which one you have chosen?

Comment: For facebook,i am using https://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID/photos api.For twitter,i am using https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update_with_media.json

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct solution to the problem but I'm putting some reference direct from respective service SDK that will point you to *somewhere* at least,

**Facebook,**

See [Facebook SDK 3.2 for iOS Reference](http://developers.facebook.com/ios/) there you can find [FBRequestConnection](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/3.2/class/FBRequestConnection), one of its delegate method, `+ (FBRequestConnection*)startForUploadPhoto:(UIImage *)photo completionHandler:(FBRequestHandler)handler` look into `FBRequestHandler` it will returns something that may useful to you.

**Twitter,**

See [Integrating with Twitter on iOS](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/ios)

You need to see for [SLRequest class](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Social/Reference/SLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012234), twitter api using this for connection to the service, read for `SLRequestHandler` one of its delegate, `- (void)performRequestWithHandler:(SLRequestHandler)handler`
, it gives `typedef void(^SLRequestHandler)(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error);`

If you get success in achieving this, you can further more look [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2267950/1603234) to calculate percentage downloaded.