# Loading object in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, ios7, xib

I was look over new apps on appstore.I saw an app and I like asynchronously download object in this app that Do you know library for do this ? How can I animate loading object like this and asynchronously download ?

image : [image]

Thank you.

Comment: There is already a `sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler` method in NSURLConnection class. Can you please specify why it is not useful for your scenario and why do you think a third party lib is required?

Comment: @AyanSengupta No ı saw an app on appstore and ı like this loading tool . I wonder how can I do like this in my apps?

Answer (score 2):

Here's one: [KAProgressLabel](https://github.com/kirualex/KAProgressLabel)

I'm using it in an app. It's pretty easy to configure/customize colors and sizes to let ik look like the controls from your screenshot. It also has a little demo app [(screenshot)](http://static.oschina.net/uploads/space/2013/1030/102518_WLux_12.png)

To track download progress I would suggest adding [`AFNetworking`](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) to your project. Use [`AFHTTPRequestOperation`](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/2.0.3/Classes/AFHTTPRequestOperation.html) to download your file and set a [`progressBlock`](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/2.0.3/Classes/AFURLConnectionOperation.html#//api/name/setDownloadProgressBlock%3a). In the progress block, use the passed parameter to update the progress in the UI.

Comment: Really thank you  and also I am asking how can I asynchronously download like in this picture ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2267950/how-to-make-an-progress-bar-for-an-nsurlconnection-when-downloading-a-file