# integrating UIProgressview in NSOperationQueue

Tags: ios, nsoperationqueue, uiprogressview

I want to integrate UIProgressView in NSOperationQueue, where i download a image and share it. i want show the progress of download of the image. even if i run in main thread. the progressive start working after the background thread, and the progress label direct shows 100% instead of continuous update . please find my code for your reference.

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]  completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(updateProgress:) withObject:[NSNumber  numberWithFloat:((100.0/response.expectedContentLength)*data.length)] waitUntilDone:YES];


        NSURL *documentsURL = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] firstObject];
        NSURL *tempURL = [documentsURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:[url lastPathComponent]];
        [data writeToURL:tempURL atomically:YES];
        [sharingItems addObject:tempURL];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self shareSheetForMedia:sharingItems];
        });
       }];

-(void) updateProgress:(NSNumber *) num {
    float percentage = [num float];
     [self.progressBar setProgress:percentage animated:YES];
    NSString *percentText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld %%", percentage];
    self.progressStatusLabel.text = percentText;
}
```

I am not sure what's going wrong. can anyone help?

Comment: Are `response.expectedContentLength` and `data.length` floats or ints? And why are you converting num to a long?

Comment: And why are you converting num to a long? setProgress is supposed to take a float as a parameter

Comment: ya changed it, even it doesn't work

Comment: Even though you said both response.expectedContentLength and data.length were floats, I just checked the docs myself and *neither* of them's a float. Convert them both.

Comment: And in general, I don't think your mathematical expression `(100.0/response.expectedContentLength)*data.length` is doing what you think...

Comment: And furthermore, since the completion block is performed after the data is finished loading, shouldn't the progress be 100% anyway?

Comment: so what should i do for the progress

Comment: possible duplicate of [NSURLConnection Progress Bar with sendAsynchronousRequest Objective-C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22564582/nsurlconnection-progress-bar-with-sendasynchronousrequest-objective-c)

Comment: Actually this ^ answer should explain things well.

Comment: Hey, but i tried that before. but i am confused how to set a delegate in a block. if i did not set delegate it will not fire the delegate methods

Comment: Then I recommend posting that code that you've tried because your current answer won't work to show the incremental progress a progress view would require.