# MBProgressHUD Hiding indicator after GCD

Tags: ios, objective-c, grand-central-dispatch, mbprogresshud

The user is able to click a button to download a set of maps, upon completion of that task, I would like to hide the progress indicator. I have tried several variants of the below code but have not achieved what I am searching for. Any guidance would be appreciated.

```
 - (IBAction)SavePhotoOnClick:(id)sender{


    HUD = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithView:self.navigationController.view];
    [self.navigationController.view addSubview:HUD];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0), ^{
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlstr1];
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]];
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil);        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
        });
    });



        // Set determinate mode
    HUD.mode = MBProgressHUDModeDeterminate;
    HUD.dimBackground = YES;
    HUD.color = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.23 green:0.50 blue:0.82 alpha:0.90];
    HUD.delegate = self;
    HUD.labelText = @"Downloading Maps";

    // myProgressTask uses the HUD instance to update progress
    [HUD showWhileExecuting:@selector(myProgressTask) onTarget:self withObject:nil animated:YES];
    }


- (void)myProgressTask {
    // This just increases the progress indicator in a loop
    float progress = 0.0f;
    while (progress < 1.0f) {
        progress += 0.01f;
        HUD.progress = progress;
        usleep(40000);
    }
}
```

Removing the progresstask method and the showWhileExecuting code removes the progress indicator. It seems that usleep overrides everything and does not allow for the progress indicator to be hidden after the download completes and instead removes it after the 4 sec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that `myProgressTask` doesn't perform any actual work: your download actually happens in your dispatch_async call. Use a call like `[hud showHUDAddedTo: self.navigationController.view animated:YES];` before you start your network request, so it will become hidden when your download completes. This will only show the spinning indicator, not a progress circle.

If you want the progress circle, you will need to use [NSURLConnection](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and its associated [delegate methods](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/NSURLConnectionDelegate) to track the progress of the download. Specifically, look at the `connection:didReceiveResponse:` method—using the `expectedContentLength` to calculate the percentage, using values you get from the `connection:didReceiveData:` method to incrementally update this progress.

Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2267950/how-to-make-an-progress-bar-for-an-nsurlconnection-when-downloading-a-file) for an example of how to do this.

Comment: This works, and I had done this previously. For some reason however when I use that call it does not allow me to add text, color, etc.. I'm not so big on the determinate status of the progress indicator, assuming I could add some text that says "downloading..." any protips?

Comment: I believe the MBProgressHUD instance has parameters like "text" that you could set to customise the appearance.

Comment: yes it does, however, those parameters don't seem to work with our current solution. I'll need to investigate it a bit more I suppose.