# AFNetworking + MBProgressHUD unable to update HUD status

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking-2, mbprogresshud

In the viewDidLoad method of my viewController I wrote something like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

self.hud = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
self.hud.labelText = @"Loading";
[serverData loadNewsData:self ];
 }
```

Basically I show the HUD and start a method loadNewsData on another class, passing the viewController.

The method in the other class is like this:

```
 -(void)loadNewsData:(LoadViewController*) loadViewController
  {

AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
[manager GET:[siteAddress stringByAppendingString:getNewsList] parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {


    loadViewController.hud.detailsLabelText = @"updating news";

    [NewsModel setNewsData:responseObject];
     loadViewController.hud.detailsLabelText = @"Finished";

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

}

When the request of the AFHTTPRequestOperation starts I was expecting to see the sub menu in the HUD to change in "Updating news". But nothing happens. I just see Finished at the end of the process. The requests takes like 10sec so I was expecting to see "updating news", but nothing.
I try also to this:

```
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
       loadViewController.hud.detailsLabelText = @"updating news"; });
```

Thinking I have to be in the UI queue to update some UI stuff, but it did not work either.
I'm a newbie probably I miss something.

thanks for any good advices.

Comment: You wouldn't have a problem if you just changing "Loading" to "Updating News" right ? Kinda looks redundant to have "Loading".

Comment: I wouldn't pass the `viewController` to the `serverData` helper object. I think it is better if you have a method in your VC that calls `loadNewsData` and has a completion block, where you can update the UI. And as the comment above, what's the difference between "Loading" and "Updating New" ?

Answer (score 1):

Try to move `loadViewController.hud.detailsLabelText = @"updating news";` before you start GET request. If you keep this inside the success block you won't see the text.

Comment: Hi, I'd really like to be able to change it inside the block.

Comment: But you can't because the success block is executed when the network call is finished... so `@"updating news"` is instantly replaced with `@"Finished"`

Comment: @GonjiDev is right. Once the success block is run, ALL the data has already been loaded... An alternative is to use a progress block if AFNetworking has one... Or your going to have to look into NSURLConnection.

Comment: So I just checked the AFNetworking docs and apparently you can progressively get data back using 
`- (void)setDownloadProgressBlock:(void (^)(NSUInteger bytesRead, long long totalBytesRead, long long totalBytesExpectedToRead))block;` Check the docs and you'll get a better understanding...

Answer (score 0):

This link should help you out... [NSURLConnection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2267950/how-to-make-an-progress-bar-for-an-nsurlconnection-when-downloading-a-file)

It describes the NSURLConnection delegate method to use and how to use it for the exact situation your in. I understand that this isn't an AFNetworking solution but if your still looking for an AFNetworking solution, check out this method `- (void)setDownloadProgressBlock:(void (^)(NSUInteger bytesRead, long long totalBytesRead, long long totalBytesExpectedToRead))block;`.

Hope this gets you in the right track.