# Show download percentage for multiple service calls

Tags: ios, objective-c, asynchronous

We are having multiple service calls to download some data which need to saved in local database to access later. Right now we are using  dispatch_async to update progress bar.

We need some text need to shown when data is downloading for each service and percentage of the data. How can we handle it

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
dispatch_async(queueForCatalog, ^{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self updateProgress:0.2];
    });
});
```

Comment: Are you using NSURLSession for downloading?

Comment: No We are using NSURLConnection

Comment: you can see this post for your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2267950/how-to-make-an-progress-bar-for-an-nsurlconnection-when-downloading-a-file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make an progress bar for an NSURLConnection when downloading a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2267950/how-to-make-an-progress-bar-for-an-nsurlconnection-when-downloading-a-file)

Comment: suggest you to upgrade to URLSession, due to apple deprecating NSURLConnection